# Delete unused records from oracle table

Tags: oracle

DB version : 11.2.0.4
OS Solaris 5.10

REQUIREMENT : Delete unused records from table only after finding if the record is being accessed or not.

We have a table employee, which has 100,000 records, if anyone select a particular record/records from employee table then, the respective record's STATUS column should get updated to 'ACTIVE' value.

This is required for auditing purpose, 60 days later we will delete all the records from employee table whose STATUS column value is is NULL. how can this be achieved?

My understanding so far, correct me if I am wrong:

1) Trigger can't be used as there is no SELECT event, we only have UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE event.
2) Oracle FGA (Fine grain auditing) may not solve the purpose. or may be I am not aware, is it doable with FGA?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPID   NUMBER,
  NAME    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SALARY  NUMBER,
  DEPART  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  STATUS  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
```

sample records:

```
     EMPID NAME                SALARY DEPART               STATUS    
---------- --------------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
       101 ALFA                  1000 IT                             
       102 BETA                  2000 CLERK                          
       103 PETER                 3000 FINANCE                        
       104 JOHN                  4000 IT                             
       105 MESSI                 5000 TECH                           
       106 ROMEO                 5000 TECH                           
       107 TERI                  5000 TECH                           
       108 ROBERT                5000 TECH
```

Example:

If any one issue below statements

query 1: `SELECT * from EMPLOYEE where name='MESSI';`

the auditing should update the STATUS='ACTIVE' of empid=105

```
     EMPID NAME                SALARY DEPART               STATUS    
---------- --------------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
       101 ALFA                  1000 IT                             
       102 BETA                  2000 CLERK                          
       103 PETER                 3000 FINANCE                        
       104 JOHN                  4000 IT                             
       105 MESSI                 5000 TECH                 'ACTIVE'                         
       106 ROMEO                 5000 TECH                           
       107 TERI                  5000 TECH                           
       108 ROBERT                5000 TECH
```

query 2: `SELECT * from EMPLOYEE where DEPART='TECH';`

The auditing should update the STATUS='ACTIVE' for empid=105,106,107,108

```
     EMPID NAME                SALARY DEPART               STATUS    
---------- --------------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
       101 ALFA                  1000 IT                             
       102 BETA                  2000 CLERK                          
       103 PETER                 3000 FINANCE                        
       104 JOHN                  4000 IT                             
       105 MESSI                 5000 TECH                 'ACTIVE'                         
       106 ROMEO                 5000 TECH                 'ACTIVE'                                                    
       107 TERI                  5000 TECH                 'ACTIVE'                                                    
       108 ROBERT                5000 TECH                 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: How can you decide whether a record has been "read" or not? Say I do a query with some filter and this query gets 3 records, but Oracle does a full scan of the table, thus "reading" all the records; what to do in this case? Or if a try a query that gets N records and then I use it in within an external query that only gets 1 row; what to do then?

Comment: You can use FGA to fire an audit, and in the policy creation, you can call a procedure created by you. In that procedure, make the changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Oracle to achieve what to want is Known as ILM or Information Lifecycle Management.
It allows you to archive, delete, move or do specific actions depending on some criterias (Such as last access).

But be aware, it requires an additional license.

I have a suggestion :

1. Enable SELECT audit on the target table
2. Create an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER that will get the inserted line in DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL et extract SQL_TEXT if the OBJECT_NAME was your table (+others checks)
3. Inside this trigger, do some string operations to get the WHERE CONDITION & use it for update.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ambiguous requirement to me.  What happens if one does select * or select count(*)?  That under the specification would make all employee records used.
The view v$SQL would contain "all" SQL statements issued, you could always look in there (going through v$plan_table with the object).  Then use those to reverse engineer if the record was touched.

Answer (score 0):

You may try FGA ( fine-grained Audit ) using the DBMS_FGA Package. Try Running the code block below in your schema. If it executes successfully , check if audits are lodged periodically in the  DBA_COMMON_AUDIT_TRAIL  or DBA_AUDIT_STATEMENT table ( check documentation ) while running a select query. Schedule a program that runs periodically to check the audit table and update the status column accordingly. I have never tried anything like this, However!.

```
BEGIN
                   dbms_fga.Add_policy(object_schema => 'HR', object_name => 'EMPLOYEE',
                   policy_name => 'STATUS_UPDATE', audit_condition => 'SELECT',
                   audit_column => 'NAME ,DEPART', handler_schema => NULL,
                   handler_module => NULL,
                   ENABLE => TRUE);
               END;

               /
```